# How to send data from html to MongoDB using Python Flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, mongodb

I am trying to develop a web application in which I want to upload multiple CSV files and transfer them to MongoDB. I have used Python Flask to develop the application.

I have created a sample file to test few concepts, in which I have achieved till browsing the file from my local desktop.
However, I want to upload the same and transfer the files to MongoDB.

Could you please help me achieve the same. I am not able to figure out how to approach to achieve the same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TheAnveshaSrivastava</title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
        <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script  src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<style> 

    .tabs-right > .nav-tabs,
    .tabs-left > .nav-tabs {
      border-bottom: 0;
    }

    .tab-content > .tab-pane,
    .pill-content > .pill-pane {
      display: none;
    }

    .tab-content > .active,
    .pill-content > .active {
      display: block;
    }


    .tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li,
    .tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li {
      float: none;
    }

    .tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a,
    .tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a {
      min-width: 74px;
      margin-right: 0;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
    }

    .tabs-left > .nav-tabs {
      float: left;
      margin-right: 19px;
      border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    }

    .tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a {
      margin-right: -1px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
         -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
              border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    }

    .tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
    .tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
      border-color: #eeeeee #dddddd #eeeeee #eeeeee;
    }

    .tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a,
    .tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a:hover,
    .tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a:focus {
      border-color: #ddd transparent #ddd #ddd;
    }
</style>
</head>
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"><h3>Tabs vertical side</h3>

          <!-- tabs left -->
          <div class="tabbable tabs-left">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab">One</a></li>
              <li class="active"><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab">Two</a></li>
              <li><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab">Twee</a></li>
              <li><a href="#d" data-toggle="tab">Four</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
             <div class="tab-pane active" id="a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, charetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
             Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero.</div>
             <div class="tab-pane" id="b">Secondo sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan. 
             Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.</div>
             <div class="tab-pane" id="c">Thirdamuno, ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
             Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae. </div>
             <div class="tab-pane" id="d">Four numero 4 damuno, ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
             Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae. </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /tabs -->

        </div>   
      </div><!-- /row -->
    </div>
    <script>
    $('.tab-pane').each(function(index) {
      const label = '<label class="btn btn-default btn-file">Browse</label>';
      const input = '<input type="file" >';
      //const button = '<button class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>';
      $(this).append( "<br /><br />", $(label).append(input) );
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, session, redirect
from flask.ext.pymongo import PyMongo
import bcrypt

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'mongologinexample'
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb://Anvesha1124:vishal@ds157509.mlab.com:57509/connect_to_mongo1124'

mongo = PyMongo(app)



@app.route('/login')
def header():
    """if 'username' in session:
        return 'You are logged in as ' + session['username']"""

    return render_template('header.html')


@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    users = mongo.db.users
    login_user = users.find_one({'name' : request.form['username']})

    if login_user:
        if bcrypt.hashpw(request.form['pass'].encode('utf-8'), login_user['password'].encode('utf-8')) == login_user['password'].encode('utf-8'):
            session['username'] = request.form['username']
            return redirect(url_for('header'))

    return 'Invalid username/password combination'

@app.route('/register', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        users = mongo.db.users
        existing_user = users.find_one({'name' : request.form['username']})

        if existing_user is None:
            hashpass = bcrypt.hashpw(request.form['pass'].encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
            users.insert({'name' : request.form['username'], 'password' : hashpass})
            session['username'] = request.form['username']
            return redirect(url_for('index'))

        return 'That username already exists!'

    return render_template('register.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = 'mysecret'
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: You don't seem to have posted any Flask code at all.

Comment: Added the Python code as well. Please check

Answer (score 0):

You can use: [Flask-PyMongo](https://flask-pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

For Example:

```
@app.route('/uploads/<path:filename>', methods=['POST'])
def save_upload(filename):
    mongo.save_file(filename, request.files['file'])
    return redirect(url_for('get_upload', filename=filename))
```